# Tkinter alignment of boxes and problem in selection

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Good day everyone. I have literally just started with `tkinter`, I'm trying to create a simple GUI for our testers to report problems with our test tool. I've been looking at videos, etc.. For about a day so keep in mind I«m pretty new at this.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


root = Tk() #Setting Tk() as a var
root.title("TestTool Reporting") #Title of the GUI
root.geometry("500x300") # Size of the GUI
root.iconbitmap(r"logo.ico")
root.resizable(0, 0) # Does not allow resizing of the window

#def submit():         TO USE LATER
#    pass

##############FRAMES#######################

#LEFT FRAME
left_frame = Frame(root)
left_frame.pack(side=LEFT)

#CHILD LEFT FRAMES
l_top_frame = Frame(left_frame, pady=5)
l_top_frame.pack(side=TOP)

l_middle_frame = Frame(left_frame, pady=5)
l_middle_frame.pack()

l_bottom_frame = Frame(left_frame, pady=5)
l_bottom_frame.pack()

#RIGHT FRAME
right_frame = Frame(root)
right_frame.pack()

#CHILD RIGHT FRAMES



#LEFT TOP FRAME LABEL + question
q1_label = Label(l_top_frame, text="Choose T24 Environment")
q1_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

q1_a = Checkbutton(l_top_frame, text="R18 VBK TEST2")
q1_a.grid(column=0, row=1)

q1_b = Checkbutton(l_top_frame, text="R19 TAFJ")
q1_b.grid(column=0, row=2)

q1_c = Checkbutton(l_top_frame, text="R16 TAFJ")
q1_c.grid(column=0, row=3)

q1_d = Checkbutton(l_top_frame, text="R18 VBK AML")
q1_d.grid(column=0, row=4)

#LEFT MIDDLE FRAME Label + question

q2_label = Label(l_middle_frame, text="Enter Test type")
q2_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

q2 = Entry(l_middle_frame, width=30)
q2.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=3)

#BOTTOM frame + Question

q3_label = Label(l_bottom_frame, text="which User you used?")
q3_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

q3_a = Checkbutton(l_bottom_frame, text="FT_INPUTTER_1")
q3_a.grid(column=0, row=1)

q3_b = Checkbutton(l_bottom_frame, text="FT_INPUTTER_2")
q3_b.grid(column=0, row=2)

q3_c = Checkbutton(l_bottom_frame, text="FT_AUTHORISER_1")
q3_c.grid(column=0, row=3)

#RIGHT FRAME LABLE + QUESTION

q4_label = Label(right_frame, text="Enter your username:")
q4_label.grid(column=0, row=1)

q4 = Entry(right_frame, width=15)
q4.grid(column=0, row=2)
```

I have two problems here I got a bit stuck with:

1. When I check box one option in questions 1, automatically same box is checked in question 3. They do not seem to be independent where did I go wrong?
2. The alignment of the options seems to not follow the grid structure and looks weird, how can I solve this?

I've tried playing around with .pack() and .grid() but nothing solved it yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ***"not seem to be independent where did I go wrong?"***: You didn't read about [The Tkinter Checkbutton Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used only the `grid` geometry manager and removed some the frame widgets that were complicating the overall design. And while I did those changes the checkboxes also worked correctly.

It solves both the issues:

1. The widget alignments
2. Multiple checkbox check issue

Hope you understand my solution.

**Code:**

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


root = Tk() #Setting Tk() as a var
root.title("TestTool Reporting") #Title of the GUI
root.geometry("325x325") # Size of the GUI
#root.iconbitmap(r"logo.ico")
root.resizable(0, 0) # Does not allow resizing of the window

#def submit():         TO USE LATER
#    pass

##############FRAMES#######################

main_frame = Frame(root)
main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

# first question
q1_label = Label(main_frame, text="Choose T24 Environment")
q1_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='w')

q1_a = Checkbutton(main_frame, text="R18 VBK TEST2")
q1_a.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='w')

q1_b = Checkbutton(main_frame, text="R19 TAFJ")
q1_b.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='w')

q1_c = Checkbutton(main_frame, text="R16 TAFJ")
q1_c.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky='w')

q1_d = Checkbutton(main_frame, text="R18 VBK AML")
q1_d.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky='w', pady=(0,20))


## second question

q2_label = Label(main_frame, text="Enter Test type")
q2_label.grid(column=0, row=5)

q2 = Entry(main_frame)
q2.grid(column=0, row=6, pady=(0,20))

# third question

q3_label = Label(main_frame, text="which User you used?")
q3_label.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky='w')

q3_a = Checkbutton(main_frame, text="FT_INPUTTER_1")
q3_a.grid(column=0, row=8, sticky='w')

q3_b = Checkbutton(main_frame, text="FT_INPUTTER_2")
q3_b.grid(column=0, row=9, sticky='w')

q3_c = Checkbutton(main_frame, text="FT_AUTHORISER_1")
q3_c.grid(column=0, row=10, sticky='w')

# fourth question

q4_label = Label(main_frame, text="Enter your username:")
q4_label.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='n', padx=(30,0))

q4 = Entry(main_frame, width=15)
q4.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='n', padx=(30,0))

root.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you for the answer rep up :)

Comment: Quick question i see you added pady = (0,20) how does it work ? i thought it only takes a single value in

Comment: `pady = (0,20)` will give `0` padding at the top and `20` padding to the bottom of the widget. Similarly, for `padx=(0,20)` will give `0` padding to the left and `20` padding to the right.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
.grid(..., sticky='w')
```

to move elements to the left (`west`)

If you add background color to `Frame` and other widgets

```
 Frame(..., bg='red')
```

then you will see if they use full `width` and you can add

```
 .pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

to change it.

(`.pack()` and `.grid()` has own options to change some elements)

---

Every `Checkbox` needs own `StringVar()`/`IntVar()` to keep information if it was checked. If you don't use it then `tkinter` may add it in weird way and two checkboxes may use the same `StringVar()`/`IntVar()`

```
v1_a = IntVar()
q1_a = Checkbutton(..., variable=v1_a)

v1_b = IntVar()
q1_b = Checkbutton(..., variable=v1_)
```

And later you can check selection

```
print(v1_a.get(), v2_a.get())
```